# He must escape from a CERN/DARPA-like facility - Research & Development

Tags: military-defense

This question is linked to this one:

[He must escape from a CERN/DARPA-like facility](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35698/he-must-escape-from-a-cern-darpa-like-facility)

Since the facility is for defense development: Which areas or topic of research and/or development could I additionally include, even currently developed weapons? My game universe is pseudo-realistic, not involved magic *a priori* so the developments should be related to actual developments in period 2012+ (you can speculate here a bit since most of the developments are kept secret from the overall world), and even better if the mentioned technology, weapon, or research area is somewhat controversial.

Comment: If you want top-secret controversial hidden weaponry genetic diseases would be likely, it is frowned upon so you would have to be secretive about it.

Comment: Genetic diseases is a good point

Comment: This question is an _idea generation question_, which is off-topic according to the scope defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 2):

### Weapons

- *mobile High Energy Laser Pulse* **(mHELP)**

  - Unleash hell with HELPs. While the technology works already in Theory, current solid state lasers are not strong enough (Some [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Weapon_System) I found).
- *Railguns*

  - Getting hit by hypersonic shells is no fun. The current problem is to generate the pulse, but a project from the US seems to have made some progress (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun#History), the project is named *Velocitas Eradico*, *Speed Kills*), even though a school-bus sized gun is probably only viable in naval warfare. But we are in a research-facility.
  - **However**: anyone with a Seismometer would probably pick up tests, so you should probably also research some magnets to catch the (metallic) projectile before impact.
- *Directional (non-nuclear) EMP* **(NNEMP)**

  - Research is already done (the biggest research facility apparentally being [TRESTLE/ATLAS-I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATLAS-I)), however more research, especially in directed EMP is always fun.

### Defense

- EMP Shielding

  - You don't want to accidentally fry your bases circuits.
- Energy Shields

  - No, not Star-Trek style that survives an Anti-Matter explosion with 60% remaining, but extremely strong magnetic currents that disable/redirect projectiles. Make sure to not get caught in these fields, as strong magnetic forces can be unhealthy (likewise to nerves, which operate also on electric currents as well as blood, which contains tiny traces of iron [remember the *strong* forces?]). As a nice sideeffect you get fields that can suspend objects in mid-air.

### Miscellaneous

- *Gravity Control*

  - If you would be able to control gravity in small areas you could do some amazing things. However, 1g is a lot to fight against, so this experiment is probably better situated at a space station.

### Really crazy stuff

- http://www.scp-wiki.net/

  - Really, all the stuff is already there. It can't possibly go crazier than that.

Comment: Honestly, after remembering the Foundation everything else would be a copy from there. The Foundation is a really good place to generate ideas.